# The kernel failed to start due to the missing module '_sqlite3'

Tags: sqlite, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-3.12

I'm trying to run an python notebook via VSCode, but i'm constantly getting the error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'`

I have searched a lot, but get no conclusions on what the problem might even be, tried reinstalling Python and this library, but apparently nothing works.

I tried several things like reinstalling Python, and trying various forms of installing sqlite2 or sqlite3, but with no success.

My expectations are to just be able to run notebook files locally.

Comment: did you try searching how to use SQLite with Python https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm